# Why does this Aperture smart album with flags & labels contain more than it should?

Tags: software, apple-aperture, photo-editing

I have tried to create a smart album in Aperture 3 that is based on this:

1) It is flagged
2) It has a label

I have followed the instructions in provided help documentation in Aperture 3. Searching the Internet does not give any answer. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

The resulting smart album contains all the images from the original album.

[image: Create new smart album]

Comment: "Any" of the following that 'match' will choose images that are either or both of these settings.

Comment: Ok, I have changed to "All". It seems to be working :)

Comment: @cmason: Could you stuff that gem of advice into an answer so we can get this puppy off the "unanswered" questions list? Many thanks! :-)

Comment: will do @jrista

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that at the top of the settings box, you have it set to choose  "  'Any' of the following..." which results in **either** or both conditions to be part of the selection.  Change it to 'All', which will mean both conditions must be true before images are added to the album.